# How to find the Cross reference of a function or a string using r2pipe?

Tags: cross-reference, malware-detection, radare2

I am working on a malware detection project where I am using both radare2 and r2pipe. I know how to find the cross references of a function and string with the help of "axt @function_address/string_address" command. But the problem is that same command is not working in r2pipe i.e. r2.cmd("axt @function_address"). Can someone please help me how to find the cross references of a function or a string using r2pipe??

Answer (score 0):

Same command is working. But the mistake which I have done was this. I have used double 'aa' instead of triple 'aaa' for analysing i.e r2.cmd('aaa').